# Why emberjs starts too slow at Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js

I have simple emberjs application created with ember-cli with commnad 
**ember new MyApp**, this application has only one template

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember</h2>
{{outlet}}
```

I'm using this app with cordova at android platform. 
When application starts, it takes 5-6 seconds before "**Welcome to Ember**" text appears. Why it is so slow? Is there any configurations I have to do for cordova project?

Comment: Are you using [ember-cli-cordova](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova)?

Comment: I tried both, clear ember-cli and with plugin ember-cli-cordova. I have tested app on real phone and on android emulator.  Result always same, application starts too slow.

Comment: Might be worth opening an issue on the project's github repo